# Copy and paste images from clipboard, blob Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I'm trying to copy and paste images from a clipboard, but I get this error message in chrome. What is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhUwn/)

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
$("body").bind("paste", function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var original =  ev.originalEvent;
    var file =  original.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var result = evt.target.result; 
        var arr = result.split(",");
        var data = arr[1]; // raw base64
        var contentType = arr[0].split(";")[0].split(":")[1];

        // this needs to post to a server route that can accept raw base64 content and save to a file            
        $.post("/echo/html/", {
            contentType: contentType,
            data: data
        });                                
        $this.append("<img src='" + result + "' />");
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that, when the browser is trying to load the file through the clipboard, it is looking for a blob type of data.

Blob, or **B** inary **L** arge **OB** ject is a lengthy string that is your object, but instead of being a file, it is just a string.

By trying to copy from the clipboard, which has a copy of the directory of the file, at least from how the error is and how your code is, that's what it looks like, it isn't a blob file type, so Chrome isn't set up to handle the actual file.

I don't know what this is for, but if you are trying to save the files on a database, then what you should do is have the image uploaded through the form, have them placed in a directory with a unique name, and store the location of each image, the actual path, on your database.

Then, you can loop through it and do what you need to do.

If you want, I post some code I have from another project where I did this, so just ask if you want it.

It will only work if you're using a MySQL server tho; the code is written in PHP.

[Blob Wiki Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object)

Comment: Thanks, this is something that I'm trying to figure out as well. I'm using FileReader to let users add a picture to a form and be able to see it before they upload it. If I save it to the database that will defeat the purpose of allowing them to preview it before they upload it. Do you think I should try using Ajax instead or that using it to allow a preview is acceptable?

Comment: @gv0029 Is it absolutely necessary to preview the image? If not, and you're using just a normal mysql database, I would be more than willing to share the code. The preview just complicates things, so if its not absolutely necessary, then everything is much easier.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately yes it is something they are pretty set on. I appreciate it all the same though!